# TapJoy showOffersWithViewController method is deprecated in Version 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated, deprecation-warning, tapjoy

I'm integrating the new version on ***TapJoy (V. 11) on iOS*** and it says that the method --> **showOffersWithViewController** is deprecated in version 11 and to go to dev.tapjoy.com to see how to fix it. However, while the documentation has been great for everything else, there doesn't seem to be any helpful information on how to remedy the deprecation of this method.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

[image]